# Items replacing but not asked

Tags: java, javafx

I'm working on a little game. So I create the game interface (countains the gun, the canvas which I use as gamespace and an interface for the user to control is gun). I place the different elements in the window and there is my problem. When I execute my code, all is well placed but once I use one of the buttons (buttons in both codes) or the slider (second code), the slider and the fire button replace themselves. And I don't understand why because I never asked this rellocation in my code. Also, when the items rellocate, I can't use any other items excepted the fire button and the slider.
Here are screenshots of what I have before using a button (first screenshot) (it's also how I want the interface to be) and the second screenshot shows the rellocation I have.

[How it looks when I use nothing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6czg.png)

[How it looks when I use a button or the slider.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKITN.png)

Main.java :

```
package application;

import bureaux.Bureau;
import canons.Canon;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    private StackPane root, rootBureau;
    private Scene scene;
    private Stage stage;
    private Text joueur;
    private Button menu, musique, ajoutJoueur;
    private FlowPane rootJeu;
    private Bureau bureauJoueur;
    private ToolBar toolBar;
    private Canon canonJoueur;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        getRoot();
        getScene();
        stage = primaryStage;

        creerInterface();

        stage.setTitle("Mad Java Guns");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void creerInterface(String mode) { // creating the gamespace and the objects that the user need to play
        getToolBar().getItems().addAll(getMusique(), getAjoutJoueur());
        getRootBureau().getChildren().add(getBureauJoueur());
        getRootJeu().getChildren().add(getCanonJoueur());
        getRoot().getChildren().addAll(getToolBar(), getJoueur(), getRootBureau(), getRootJeu());
    }

    // Getters
    public StackPane getRoot() {
        if(root == null) {
            root = new StackPane();
        }
        return root;
    }

    public Scene getScene() {
        if(scene == null) {
            scene = new Scene(root,1000,800);
        }
        return scene;
    }

    public Text getJoueur() { // gamespace
        if(joueur == null) {
            joueur = new Text("Espace de jeu");
            joueur.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20));
            joueur.setTranslateY(120);
        }
        return joueur;
    }

    public ToolBar getToolBar() {
        if(toolBar == null) {
            toolBar = new ToolBar();
            toolBar.setTranslateY(122);
            toolBar.setTranslateX(3);
            toolBar.setStyle("-fx-background-color: transparent");
        }
        return toolBar;
    }

    public Button getMusique() { // button too change the music in game
        if (musique == null) {
            musique = new Button("Musique");
            musique.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println("musique"); // not coded yet
            });
            musique.setFocusTraversable(false);
        }
        return musique;
    }

    public Button getAjoutJoueur() { // add players in the game
        if(ajoutJoueur == null) {
            ajoutJoueur = new Button("Ajouter un joueur");
            ajoutJoueur.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println("ajoutJoueur"); //not coded yet
            });
            ajoutJoueur.setFocusTraversable(false);
        }
        return ajoutJoueur;
    }

    public StackPane getRootBureau() { // pane where the user's interface will be placed
        if(rootBureau == null) {
            rootBureau = new StackPane();
            rootBureau.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightgrey");
            rootBureau.setMaxSize(990, 250);
            rootBureau.setTranslateY(270);
        }
        return rootBureau;
    }

    public Bureau getBureauJoueur() { // user's interface
        if(bureauJoueur == null) {
            bureauJoueur = new Bureau("Billy", getCanonJoueur());
        }
        return bureauJoueur;
    }
}
```

Class Bureau.java :

```
package bureaux;

import canons.Canon;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class Bureau extends Parent {
    private Slider sliderCanon;
    private HBox boxPrincipale;
    private VBox boxControlesCanon;
    private Button feu;

    public Bureau(String nom, Canon canon) {
        getBoxControlesCanon().getChildren().addAll(getSliderCanon(), getFeu());
        getBoxPrincipale().getChildren().add(getBoxControlesCanon());

        this.setTranslateX(-480); // placing the boxes
        this.setTranslateY(-95);
        this.getChildren().add(getBoxPrincipale());
    }

    //Getteurs
    public HBox getBoxPrincipale() {
        if(boxPrincipale == null) { // return a HBox which countains the VBox (next function)
                                // and other elements which aren't created yet.
            boxPrincipale = new HBox();
        }
        return boxPrincipale;
    }

    public VBox getBoxControlesCanon() { // return a VBox which countains the controls of the gun 
                                    //(gun not showed in the code, doesn't concern the problem)
        if(boxControlesCanon == null) {
            boxControlesCanon = new VBox();
            boxControlesCanon.setSpacing(20);
        }
        return boxControlesCanon;
    }

    public Slider getSliderCanon() { //slider to orient the gun (gun not showed in the code, doesn't concern the problem)
        if(sliderCanon == null) {
            sliderCanon = new Slider(0, 360, 0);
            sliderCanon.setOrientation(Orientation.VERTICAL);
            sliderCanon.valueProperty().addListener(e -> {
                System.out.println(sliderCanon.getValue());
            });
            sliderCanon.setShowTickMarks(true);
            sliderCanon.setShowTickLabels(true);
            sliderCanon.setMajorTickUnit(90f);
        }
        return sliderCanon;
    }

    public Button getFeu() { // fire button
        if(feu == null) {
            feu = new Button("Feu");
            feu.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
                System.out.println("Feu");
            });
            feu.setFocusTraversable(false);
        }
        return feu;
    }
}
```

Please ask for more informations if necessary. Thanks for your help.

EDIT : sorry for the unpoliteness on top of this text, I used to edit it and add "Hello" but it just don't want to show it :/

Comment: Create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Bureau extends Parent`. You will have to be more specific and used the nodes that will produce the outcome you need.

Try something like `Bureau extends HBox`. Then

```
getBoxControlesCanon().getChildren().add(new VBox(getSliderCanon(), getFeu()));
```

To get the left alignment, you may need to do something like

```
getBoxControlesCanon().getChildren().addAll(new VBox(getSliderCanon(), getFeu()), someOtherNode);
HBox.setHGrow(someOtherNode, Priority.ALWAYS);
```

If you look at [Parent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html) compared to [VBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html), you will see that Parent does not describe how children nodes will be laid out. A lot of nodes that are a subclass of Parent do describe how their children nodes will be laid out.

Comment: I tried what you wrote. But, as I replace Parent by HBox, the last 3 lines of my constructor doesn't work. So I can't verify if it works because my HBox does not appear.

Comment: Your third line is probably okay. The two translate lines need to go.

Comment: I think the problem may be caused by the slider. I cancelled the two lines you asked me to cancel but it still replaces some pixels up and some pixels left. As i had at the beginning. This is how my code look now : `public Bureau(String nom, Canon canon) {
      can = canon;
      getBoxControlesCanon().getChildren().addAll(getSliderCanon(), getFeu());
      getBoxPrincipale().getChildren().add(getBoxControlesCanon());
      HBox.setHgrow(getBoxControlesCanon(), Priority.ALWAYS);
  
      this.getChildren().add(getBoxPrincipale());
 }`